# How do I create an info window in a costume google maps path symbol

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

So i'm working on a project that has some moving symbols of some planes moving on a polyline as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kJI7.png)

My symbol is declared here

```
 var planeSymbol = {             path: 'M 8.1326447,0.80527736 C 8.5471666,0.063577346 9.742752,0.030177346 10.052431,0.82497736 C 10.093464,3.0114774 10.134497,5.1980774 10.17553,7.3845774 C 12.760407,8.9653774 15.345284,10.546179 17.930161,12.127079 C 17.930161,12.881779 17.930161,13.636479 17.930161,14.391179 C 15.373077,13.579479 12.815993,12.767779 10.258908,11.956179 C 10.27281,13.280479 10.286713,14.604879 10.300615,15.929279 C 10.8565,16.555879 11.412385,17.182479 11.96827,17.809079 C 12.25527,18.269479 12.437605,19.641079 11.59784,19.085079 C 10.804104,18.802179 10.010367,18.519179 9.21663,18.236279 C 8.3133108,18.620779 7.4099916,19.005279 6.5066724,19.389779 C 6.3952441,18.705879 6.2272708,17.857479 6.8519879,17.359679 C 7.2927717,16.882879 7.7335555,16.406079 8.1743393,15.929279 C 8.1465467,14.604879 8.1187541,13.280479 8.0909615,11.956179 C 5.5894706,12.824879 3.0879797,13.693479 0.58648883,14.562179 C 0.54479393,13.821679 0.50309893,13.081079 0.46140403,12.340579 C 3.0184842,10.717079 5.5755645,9.0935778 8.1326447,7.4700774 C 8.1326447,5.2484774 8.1326447,3.0268774 8.1326447,0.80527736 z',
                scale: 1,
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokecolor: 'black',
                strokeWeight: 1,
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 9)
        };
```

So as i'm a newbie with google maps i tried somethings like a mouseover info window and i replaced marker with the var name planesymbol

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(planeSymbol, 'mouseover', (function(planeSymbol) {
        return function() {
            var content = address;
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, planeSymbol);
        }
      })(planeSymbol));
```

But it didn't work, so you guys have any idea how can I show a info window with different content for each plane just with mouseover?

Comment: Try putting address (and content, if it were different) as a parameter in the function. ...  'mouseover',  (function(planeSymbol, address) { ... })(planeSymbol, address));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Marker objects

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

You define a Marker object for your plane, change the default image with your plane icon and create a content bubble to use within Marker click event.

Reference should have enough info to make everything

Comment: But if I do that, can I have the marker moving on the polyline? Because i saw in the google maps API forum that they use pathsymbol. They say that "Symbols are useful when you want to use a vector-based icon on a marker, or add an image to a polyline.", so I wonder if I can replace that with a Marker if they say it is a property of the marker, and if I can, how can I do it? Thx a lot for the answer

Comment: Well... you can update the position of your marker as you want... so I supose that you can make it move along your polyline just with a loop through your polyline points and a timeout

Comment: So they say that, "Single locations on the map are displayed using markers. Markers may sometimes display custom icon images, in which case they are usually referred to as icons." and " Use a symbol to customize the icon on a marker or add images to a polyline. ". So I can´t insert the marker in the polyline because the marker is fixed on a single point and I think it cant always change the coordinates to "move", or am I wrong?

Comment: Marker class has a SetPosition method to change it's coordinates. I supose that you can change those whithout having to destroy and recreate the object.